# MongoDB M0 cluster, python multithreading

Tags: python, mongodb, multithreading, pymongo

I have a python application that web scrapes and leverages a mongo database for maintaining records. At some points in execution there is a large amount of db requests coming in and out. When this happens, the server forces my requests shut and gives the following error in the cluster:

`Connections % of configured limit has gone above 80`

What is the best practice for using pymongo with threads? I figured like other DMBS' mongodb would automatically handle scheduling of concurrent requests. Do I need to just make a local cluster or upgrade my current one to more connections?

Comment: I tried to go fix this by adding a max pool size keyword arg to the initialization of the client but that didn't work. I want to be able to do this without having to implement my own locks for incoming requests. I can do the manual solution, but it is silly as I think I should be able to accomplish this small task. Also to further specify, in python I get the following error:```indexerror : deque is empty```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical activity in the case is to create input queue.Queue and put tasks in it and create several workers to take tasks from the Queue. If you need to limit number of workers which can access resource simultanoysly use threading.Semaphore or threading.Lock Hope the answer will be helpful for you, feel free to ask questions.

```
import threading as thr
from queue import Queue


def work(input_q):
    """the function take task from input_q and print or return with some code changes (if you want)"""
    while True:
        item = input_q.get()
        if item == "STOP":
            break

        # else do some work here
        print("some result")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_q = Queue()
    urls = [...]
    threads_number = 8 # experiment with the number of workers
    workers = [thr.Thread(target=work, args=(input_q,),) for i in range(threads_number)]
    # start workers here
    for w in workers:
        w.start

    # start delivering tasks to workers 
    for task in urls:
        input_q.put(task)

    # "poison pillow" for all workers to stop them:

    for i in range(threads_number):
        input_q.put("STOP")

    # join all workers to main thread here:

    for w in workers:
        w.join

    # show that main thread can continue

    print("Job is done.")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I hadn't even thought of pooling the threads into worker groups!